# Forecast in list of lists

Tags: r

I face a problem in forecasting time series in many subcategories.

I have data in matrix of 10 variables and 19040 obseravtions.
(variables:Product Category, subcategory, Group code, Year, Month, Units, Net sales)

I've turned my matrix to a list in lists using this code.

```
        datar<-aggregate(`Net Sales`~`01. Product Info 01.02 Subcategory    Year+Month,data=BESTDOCFORANALYSIS,FUN=sum)


       datal<- datar[order(datar[,1],datar[,2]),]

       tskots<-function(x){ts(x,end=c(2017,9),frequency=12)}

       ksts<-tapply(datal$`Net Sales`,datal$`01.Product             Subcategory `,tskots)
```

I want to run a function in each subcategory.

```
            for(i in 1:60){
              fitarima[i]<-auto.arima(ksts[i])
              fitets[i]<-ets(ksts[i])
               if (fitarima[i]$AIC>=fitets[i]$AIC)
                         {fitmodel[i]<-fitarima[i]}
               else
                     {fitmodel[i]<-fitets[i]}
                 k[i]<-forecast(fitmodel[i],5)
              }
```

in order to choose best model and  forecast for each subcategory.
But i'm getting  this message

Error in is.constant(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

What you do propose to do?